# PHP, mysqli arrays

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I am new to php and mysql. I have a database with a table `user_entries` and two columns `max_val` and `num`.

I have used the following code to extract my two columns into arrays and then use the below function `numberTimesOver` to determine how many times `$num[$i] > $limit` when `$val[$i] = 10`. The numbers range from 0 to 10.

When I use my function with my two arrays from my table I get an output of zero, when it should be 4. When I use my `$a` and `$b` arrays I get an output of 2.

Where am I going wrong? I think I am going wrong when I try to convert my table columns into arrays.

```
<?php
require_once('functions.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', NULL, 'practice');

$val_sql = "SELECT `max_val` FROM `user_entries`";
$valData = $mysqli->query($val_sql);

$num_sql = "SELECT `num` FROM `user_entries`";
$numData = $mysqli->query($num_sql);

$val = array();
while($row = $valData->fetch_assoc())
{
    $val[]= $row;
}

$num = array();
while ($row = $numData->fetch_assoc())
{
    $num[] = $row;
}

//$a = [10, 4, 5, 8, 3];
//$b = [10, 6, 10, 10, 2];

function numberTimesOver($number, $max, $limit) {

    $sum = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($max); $i++)
    {
        if ($max[$i] == 10 && $number[$i] > $limit)
        {
            $sum += 1;
        }
    }
    print($sum);
}

numberTimesOver($val, $num, 6)
```

Comment: Your code will return arrays like this `[["num" => 10], ["num" => 6], ["num" => 10], ...]`. Obviously, your `numberTimesOver` function is not set to deal with this format as it expects each array item to be a scalar (integer) value. Also, why two queries? Without an `ORDER BY` clause, there's no guarantee the indexed entries of `$val` and `$num` will belong to the same tuples

Comment: Okay, I understand now that the fetch_assoc will not return the array in an integer form which is why it is not working. And I used two queries so I could extract both columns separately. I saw ORDER BY and wasn't too sure how to go about it, so I thought this might work instead. How would I go about turning the arrays into integers arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're approaching this from the wrong angle.

It looks like you want to count the number of rows where `max_val` is greater than `$limit` (6) and `num` is equal to 10.

Relational databases are **very** good at this sort of thing. All you need is the following...

```
$maxVal = 6;
$num = 10;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(
    'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `user_entries` WHERE `max_val` > ? AND `num` = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $maxVal, $num);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($sum);
$stmt->fetch();

echo $sum;
```

To summarise...

1. I've created a `COUNT` query as that's the data you're after. The query includes the parameters / conditions required in the `WHERE` clauses.
2. The `prepare` method prepares an SQL statement. With this, you can bind parameters (see next point). Think of the query as a function and the `?` characters as arguments to that function. Reference - http://php.net/manual/mysqli.prepare.php
3. `bind_param` binds the PHP variables to be used as parameters to the query. These are in the order that the `?` characters appear. The `"ii"` string denotes the format, `i` meaning *integer*, so two integers. See http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
4. `execute` simply executes the query on the database server. See http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.execute.php
5. `bind_result` binds the statement column results (in order) to the supplied PHP variables. As we only have one column (`COUNT(1)`), we only need to bind one variable (`$sum`). See http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php
6. `fetch` simply fetches the next row result and populates the bound result variables. As a `COUNT` statement only has one row, we only need to run this once. See http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: @user3788874 Do have a look at this approach!

Comment: I truthfully don't fully understand what you have done, but it works. You are awesome, thanks very much and thanks Thauwa for helping. :D I will now try to understand this before I continue.

Comment: @user3788874 I'd be happy to explain anything you don't understand and there's always the PHP manual if you need clarification on the *mysqli* methods I've used.

Comment: Okay well I get that the mysqli->prepare is just getting the columns and only the values where maxVal > 6 and num = 10, cause I tested it on other columns I need this for and it worked. Firstly why does putting the ? in work when I change the column names but leave the variables $maxVal = 6 and  $num = 10, the same? After that it would be what exactly does the bind_param and bind_result do?

Comment: @user3788874 I've updated my answer with some more information

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$val[]= $row['max_val'];
```

and

```
$num[] = $row['num'];
```

instead.

Comment: I tried this and changed it, now I am coming up with errors when I am trying to use the function. "Call to undefined function".

Comment: Are you sure that you have the line `function numberTimesOver($number, $max, $limit) {` and the code that follows in your test script?

Comment: I have it in a different .php file and I have used the require_once function to call it. It works with my $a and $b arrays. So I know the function is working, so i don't think it worked. I am not sure why though.